# Using BUNDLE_FROZEN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I often see the following line in Dockerfiles

```
ENV BUNDLE_FROZEN=true
```

I checked bundler docs and it says "Disallow changes to the Gemfile".
But I'm confused why someone would want to disallow people to change Gemfile. After all we may add new gems as a project evolves. Could someone explain why we need this env var, how, and when we use it and why it is often appears in Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 7):

This environment variable changes the behavior of bundler if it detects a difference between the `Gemfile` and the accompanying `Gemfile.lock`.

By default, when running `bundle install`, bundler will try to update the `Gemfile.lock` if there were any gems added or constraints changed. On production deployments, this is often undesirable since this may cause unexpected versions of gems to be installed which were not fully tested.

By setting `BUNDLE_FROZEN=true`, bundler will (1) require an existing `Gemfile.lock` and (2) will refuse to update this `Gemfile.lock` with updated information. This ensures that your production deployment only ever uses the exact gem versions locked into your commited `Gemfile.lock`.

The workflow here is that each time you add gems to your `Gemfile` or update existing gems, you would also run `bundle install` resp. `bundle update` on your local computer to update the `Gemfile.lock`. Afterwards, you can test the changes and finally commit the updated `Gemfile.lock`. When you later deploy your application, both files are in sync. With `BUNDLE_FROZEN=true` you can then be sure to use the exact environment in production as you have specified and tested during development.

In the end, this is basically a fail-safe to force you (and your colleagues) to actively update the `Gemfile.lock` after you changed the `Gemfile` or any dependencies. If you always do this already (and you are sure of that), you don't need to set `BUNDLE_FROZEN` in production. If you set it however, bundler will fail loudly if you forgot that rather than silently install gem versions you may not have fully tested.

Comment: I still can't understand what the point of using BUNDLE_FROZEN is. When I do changes I first do it locally: install necessary gems, write code, writes tests, get the changes reviewed,... push my code to the Github or other repo, and finally deploy. At what stage do I need to set BUNDLE_FROZEN to true? It is not set on my local/dev env, is it? Also, why would I be disallowed to update Gemfile.lock on production if I really want to install new gems, for example using Capistrano?

Comment: You would only set it in production, not on your local development machine. In production, you generally want bundler to only install the exact gem versions specified in the `Gemfile.lock` (i.e. the exact gem versions you have tested). With that, you can be reasonably sure that there are no changes in any gem dependencies which you have not yet seen and explicitly approved.

Comment: First of all, I never used this BUNDLE_FROZEN flag and still everything works fine. But my question was "Why should I set BUNDLE_FROZEN=true and not be able to update Gemfile even if I need to update?" Again, I always install what I push to Github and that code is tested and reviewed and I install exactly those version of Gems what I specify explicitly in my Gemfile. What does it have to do with BUNDLE_FROZEN.

Comment: I can't even imagine a situation when a BUNDLE_FROZEN could be useful. Basically when we make changes (for example we may add a new Gem) we run `bundle install` locally and hence the Gemfile.lock is updated. Without `bundle install` all your tests will fail and you can't deploy. Then we push and deploy. So, why do we need BUNDLE_FROZEN? If we set BUNDLE_FROZEN to true then it means I can't even deploy because it doesn't allow to update Gemfile.lock. It is an absurd.

Comment: @HardFork deployment should not update `Gemfile.lock`, so "If we set BUNDLE_FROZEN to true then it means I can't even deploy because it doesn't allow to update Gemfile.lock" is not true. This is to prevent people or programs on the production server from tampering the installation. IMO it is  NOT USEFUL, if someone really wants to install or test a different version of the gem in production, why not, as long as they know what they're doing.